# how to put a void function into a separate page on a separate dart file

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using a switch case void function to populate a part of my app with widgets dependant on what the user has input at the start.

here is a small section of my void function:

```
var DisplayLeft = Container();

void Display(String selected) {
  switch (selected) {
    case 'option 1':
      tacOpDisplayLeft = Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Button3(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            Button5(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      break;
    case 'option 2':
      tacOpDisplayLeft = Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Button1(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            Button3(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = val;
                });
              },
            ),
            Button7(
              onTap: (val) {
                setState(() {
                  selected = val;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
      break;

default:
      DisplayLeft = Container();
      break;
  }
}
```

When the void function is in my main stateful widget, it works fine. the problem is the void function is very long and I was hoping to move it to its own class I can then call on. i tried putting it in it's own class class Display{} but then the SetState is throwing up and error because it isn't in a stateful widget.
Is it possible to pass an onTap out of the class like I have done for stateless widgets that make up the Buttons?

Thanks so much and any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How about extracting your function as a separate `statefulwidget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can do it, something like this:

As I commented, create a *separate* `StatefulWidget` that accepts a `Function`:

```dart
class Display extends StatefulWidget {
  final String selected;
  final Function onSelected;
  const Display({Key? key, required this.selected, required this.onSelected})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Display> createState() => _DisplayState();
}

class _DisplayState extends State<Display> {
  // --> Using `late` since we're initializing it later on - in initState.
  late Widget tacOpDisplayLeft;

  void display(String selected) {
    switch (selected) {
      case 'option 1':
        tacOpDisplayLeft = Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Button3(
                onTap: (val) {
                  widget.onSelected(val);
                },
              ),
              Button5(
                onTap: (val) {
                  widget.onSelected(val);
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
        break;

      default:
        tacOpDisplayLeft = Container();
        break;
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    tacOpDisplayLeft = Container();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return tacOpDisplayLeft;
  }
}
```

And now you can call it from within a *separate* class:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var _tacOpSelected = 'option 1';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Display(
      selected: 'option 1',
      onSelected: (val) {
        setState(() {
          _tacOpSelected = val;
        });
      },
    );
  }
}
```